# call REST API in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I design a login form in `xamarin` Form PCL and I want to call a my webservice that will return JSON. For this, I created two functions for the same but both are n is not returning values.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
async void OnLoginButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (usernameEntry.Text != "" && passwordEntry.Text != "")
        {
             var response = GetLoginDetails(usernameEntry.Text,passwordEntry.Text);
              var getData = await getDataFromService(usernameEntry.Text, passwordEntry.Text);

        }

    }

 public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetLoginDetails(string username, string password)
    {
      try
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://mywebserverIP/api/Users?Username=" + username + "&Password=" + password);
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            return response;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

public static async Task<dynamic> getDataFromService(string username, string password)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var responseText = await client.GetStringAsync("http://mywebserverIP/api/Users?Username=" + username + "&Password=" + password);
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText);
            return data;
        }

    }
```

Thanks for your comment in Advance.

Comment: What is the desired behavior? The question in its current state is still unclear.

Comment: @Nkosi i want to authenticate the user and password form API if this authentication success then it will return the a list of json Of User. And after successfully authentication i will redirect to another form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you not **awaiting** the first method , request thread will not wait till it returns the value so , 1st change you have to make is to

```
var response = await GetLoginDetails()
```

For the second method

```
var getData = await getDataFromService()
```

I do not see any issue. I am not sure how you know that this method is not returning any values. Better to log the response of the both the method call and check.

Answer (score 0):

Use await.
First in the

```
var response = await GetLoginDetails(...
```

then maybe in the deserializeobject method too (this one i'm not sure)

```
dynamic data = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText));
```